# How to install packages required for Caffe on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, caffe, yum

I'm trying to install caffe on a Amazon Linux AMI. It has "yum" package manager. When I look at requirements, I see that, I have to run the following command:

```
sudo yum install gflags-devel glog-devel lmdb-devel
```

However, when I do this, I always get the following error:

```
No package gflags-devel available.
No package glog-devel available.
No package lmdb-devel available.
```

So, this command is from the official web page of caffe and therefore I believe there is no mistake in the installation command. My question is how can I fix the problem ? I'm a newbie on this issues and therefore sorry if my question is so simple.

Note : I know that there is a pre-installed caffe AMI available but I need to install it on my own instance.

**EDIT**

The only thing I could find is the that instance is Linux AMI 2016.03 Release.

**EDIT2**

I was able to install the aforamentioned packages by enabling other repositories as explained [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/265523) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/).
As a final step I have to install `opencv-devel` package but guess what? Thanks to Amazon Linux AMI it does not exist too! So, if is there anyone who could tell me how could I solve this new problem, I'd be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install opencv from source. 
Linux AMI is based on cent OS. [Here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-opencv-on-centos-7) is a guide while wil help you to install opencv from source.
Link:https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-opencv-on-centos-7

Comment: Thank you for this link, which might provide some limited, immediate help. An answer [should include sufficient context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/206345) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.